# Minimizing the Frobenius Norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I would like to minimize the following expression with respect to matrix X:
$$\left \| A-BX \right \|_{F}$$
where A and B matrices are given and all the matrices have positive integer elements.
Any hints?

Comment: How large problems are you targeting?

Comment: A shape (8, 3), maximum element 28594, B shape(8, T), where T is max 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem you have appears to be trivial for state-of-the-art MIQP solvers (i.e., branch and bound/cut). It is solved to 5-6 digits of accuracy in 0s. There might be smarter ways to solve the problem, but I reckon not much smarter, as it is a combinatorial problem by nature. Heuristics might work very well though, in case you don't care about optimality certificates.

Your data distribution was not given, but based on what you have told us, I've implemented a test with the MATLAB Toolbox YALMIP below (disclaimer, developed by me). The MIQP solvers I tried were Gurobi and Cplex, and the built-in solver bnb (which is absolutely terrible, but works ok here)

```
T = 10;
A = ceil(rand(8,3)*1e4);
B = ceil(randn(8,T)*100);
X = intvar(T,3,'full');
Z = A-B*X;
Constraints = [X>=0];
Objective = Z(:)'*Z(:);
optimize(Constraints,Objective)
```

BTW, if you have large numbers in both $A$ and $B$, I would work with a model which avoids squaring and multiplying that data

```
Z = intvar(8,3,'full');
Constraints = [Z == A - B*X, X>=0];
Objective = Z(:)'*Z(:);
optimize(Constraints,Objective)
```

Of course, one could use the original form

```
Constraints = [X>=0];    
Objective = norm(A-B*X,'fro')
optimize(Constraints,Objective)
```

but that leads to a MISOCP, which is solved much slower by the solvers above.

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed. Nice toolbox btw.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I didn't realize that $X$ was required to be positive as well.

Are you sure a clean solution exists?

Since $BX$ is monotonic in all entries of $X$, dynamic programming can solve the problem in time pseudopolynomial in the magnitudes of the entries of $A$; this approach will only be practical for small $A$ however.

Branch and bound codes like MIQPBB will work, and would be the first thing I'd try if I had to solve the problem in practice. See also [this paper](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-13036-6_22) for an algorithm that alleges to take advantage of the convexity of the problem.

Does the nonnegativity lead to even better specialized algorithms? It's possible, though I don't see it at the moment. Your problem is closely related to other notable optimization problems, such as a modified closest vector problem: given a point in the first orthant and $n$ vectors in that orthant, what positive linear combination of those vectors brings you closest to the point? I did a quick literature search and didn't turn up much of relevance, but it could be out there...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, this problem originated from a computer science problem, so I am not sure, if a "clean" solution exists.I also know some other constraints on the elements of B: max 10, but the elements of A can be infinitely large. I also considered DP, but I do not have a clear idea.

Comment: The DP works essentially the same way as in the unbounded knapsack problem; the extra wrinkle is that you have to keep going until $BX$ is twice the norm of $A$. I can sketch more details but if $A$ is large it's not going to be the way you want to go.

Comment: I'd check out branch and bound methods, which should work well as long as your problem is not too large. The basic idea is this: you first solve the problem with the constraint that $X \geq 0$ but no integer constraint. Then you look at the objective function: it looks like a bowl near the optimum, with elliptic level sets. You want to pick a level set that encloses at least one, but not too many, integer lattice points; you know the integer solution has to be one of these points, and they can be checked directly.